# How to hide a child container of a viewstack?

Tags: apache-flex

I have a tabbar whose dataprovider is a viewstack and the viewstack contains a group of vbox containers. I am trying to hide one of the vboxes based on a certain condition but the tabbar still shows the corressponding tab for the hidden vbox. I set the visibilty and includeinlayout of the vbox to false but the tab still exists.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove your container from the viewstack :

```
viewstack.removeChild(yourContainer)
```

Comment: This worked but I would like to understand how does the tabbar still sees the hidden vbox. Do you know why?
Thanks

Comment: This is because, like all of the other components that use a data provider, the tabbar determines how many tabs to show based on what elements are in the provider, not whether or not those elements are visible.